# Calculate the following limit : $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x) dx$

Tags: integration, limits

Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, and $g_n(x)  : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ a function defined as :
$$g_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if}\  x\geq \frac{1}{n} \\ n & \text{if}\  x<\frac{1}{n} \end{cases}$$
Calculate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x)dx$$
I tried to apply Chasles rule and :
$$\int_0^{1/n} f(x)g_n(x) dx +\int_{1/n}^1 f(x)g_n(x) dx$$
And using $g_n(x)$ definition we'll have :
$$\int_{1/n}^1 n f(x) dx $$
And I think this is false, any help ?

Comment: You think what is false? Also, $g_n$ is 0 exactly on the other part of the interval.

Comment: $\lim \int_{1/n}^1 nf(x) dx = \int_{0}^1 \infty dx $ 

Comment: So 1) be careful commuting limits and integrals 2) if that was the right integral, then yes, the result would be $+\infty$, but it isn't. $g_n(x)=0$ for $x>1/n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for average value of $ f(x) $ gives

$$n\int_0^{\frac 1n}f(x)dx=$$
$$n\Bigl(\frac 1n-0\Bigr)f(c_n)=$$
$$f(c_n)$$

with

$$0\le c_n\le \frac 1n$$

when $ n $ goes to infinity, $ c_n \to 0 $ and

$$f(c_n)\to f(0) \text{ by continuity of } f$$

So, the limit is $ f(0) $.

Comment: (+1) The best approach (and for beating to this solution), this formula (La deuxième formule de la moyenne) is literally a masterpiece in analysis.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error: in fact
$$
\int_0^1 g_n(x)f(x)\mathrm dx=\int_0^{1/n}nf(x)\mathrm dx
$$

Hint:

1. Use continuity of $f$ to fix $\epsilon>0$ so that $f(0)-\epsilon<f(x)<f(0)+\epsilon$ for $|x|<1/n$.
2. Multiply this inequality by $g_n=n$ on this interval, and integrate on $[0,1/n]$.

Comment: Nice approach for the ending, I'd seen a different method using a substitution $u = \frac1n$ and using the FTC but I think I prefer yours, more straightforward and less heavy artillery